# Arc routing problem with triangle inequality violated

Tags: distance, cplex, vehicle-routing

I want to solve an arc routing problem using cplex library.

I keep bumping into problems as the solution provided "teleports" and does not show a proper path. The problem violates the triangle inequality and I think that is the main issue here.

Even though nodes 2 and 3 are nearly at the same position, the lines going from 1 to 2 and 1 to 3 have two different distances (6 and 9, respectively). It is a must to visit all the lines.

The solution should be: 0->1, 1->2, 2->3, 3->1, 1->0

I get:

```
Route:  
Travel from node 0 to node 3 
Travel from node 1 to node 0 
Travel from node 2 to node 1 
Travel from node 3 to node 2
```

My distance matrix looks like:

```
distances = np.array([
    #0    1     2   3
    [0,   0.5,  5,  5], #0
    [0.5, 0,    6,  9], #1
    [5,   6,    0,  0], #2
    [5,   9,    0,  0]  #3
])
```

[image]

So my question is how I can solve it? When I look into cplex examples, all of them assume that triangle inequality is satisfied. How can I work around it? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

let me use your data with a very tiny example : https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/tspremovecircuit.mod

.mod

```
int     n       = ...;
range   Cities  = 1..n;

// Edges -- sparse set
tuple       edge        {int i; int j;}
setof(edge) Edges       = {<i,j> | ordered i,j in Cities};
float         dist[Edges] = ...;

// Decision variables
dvar boolean x[Edges];

 {int} nodes={i.i | i in Edges} union {i.j | i in Edges};

range r=1..-2+ftoi(pow(2,card(nodes)));


{int} nodes2 [k in r] = {i | i in nodes: ((k div (ftoi(pow(2,(ord(nodes,i))))) mod 2) == 1)};

 

 

/*****************************************************************************
 *
 * MODEL
 *
 *****************************************************************************/

// Objective
minimize sum (<i,j> in Edges) dist[<i,j>]*x[<i,j>];
subject to {
   
   // Each city is linked with two other cities
   forall (j in Cities)
        sum (<i,j> in Edges) x[<i,j>] + sum (<j,k> in Edges) x[<j,k>] == 2;
        
   // Subtour elimination constraints.
 
   
forall(k in r)  // all subsets but empty and all
    sum(e in Edges:(e.i in nodes2[k]) && (e.j in nodes2[k])) x[e]<=card(nodes2[k])-1;  

 }  
 
 
 setof(edge) solEdges       ={e | e in Edges : x[e]==1};
 execute
 {
   writeln(solEdges);
 }
```

.dat

```
n=4;

dist=[0.5,  5,  5,6,  9,0];
```

give

```
/ solution (optimal) with objective 11.5
 {<1 2> <1 4> <2 3> <3 4>}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Can you go into more details on what you did? How would you also solve the problem by saying that there is a capacity constraint? How about solving this problem using dynamic programming?